# WPF listbox is causing a stackoverflow when it has a button as a child

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, stack-overflow

When trying to add a button as the datatemplate to a listbox, I ran into a stackoverflow. When using a textbox instead, there is no stackoverflow. What is causing this? I'm using Visual Studios 2012 Update 4.

XAML code:

```xml
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CausesStackOverflow}">

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
                <Button Content="{Binding Path=.}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>

    </ListBox>

</Window>
```

C# code:

```cs
namespace StackOverflowTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public string[] CausesStackOverflow { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            CausesStackOverflow = new string[] { "Foo" };
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not "binding something to itself." The button's content is being bound to a string in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button is a ContentControl, which also uses a DataTemplate for its Content. A default DataTemplate ends up in recursively creating Buttons to display the "outer" Button's Content.

You should set the ListBox's `ItemTemplate` explicitly:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CausesStackOverflow}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves both my issue of the StackOverflow and satiates my curiosity as to why.